# Why do browsers use or display expired SSL certificates?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, ssl, certificate

The SSL certificate (of Let's Encrypt) of one of our websites (https://edu.electrosuisse.ch) expired yesterday morning. It has renewed itself using the services of Let's Encrypt several days ago. Yet the browsers that already got the old certificate seem still to be using the expired one without showing any warnings. [Shift] + Reload does not fix this.

If you open a browser window in 'private mode' then the new one is being used. But this does not update the cert of the regular browser window, neither.

(Also online SSL check tools show the new SSL certificate.)

Same behaviour for Firefox as with Chrome/Edge Chromium.

So there seems not to be any problem, but does anybody know why browsers do behave like this?

(Unfortunately search engines just deliver results for problems with expired certs etc.)

#### Info displayed in *regular* browser window

**Validity**

Not Before: Fri, 27 Nov 2020 04:43:23 GMT

Not After: Thu, 25 Feb 2021 04:43:23 GMT

#### Info displayed in *private* browser window

**Validity**

Not Before: Tue, 26 Jan 2021 07:47:26 GMT

Not After: Mon, 26 Apr 2021 07:47:26 GMT

Comment: A January valid date is displayed regardless if I use a private session or not, so the reason you are getting different certificates has nothing to do with that.  Regardless the certificate is valid. The certificate indicates it expires in 3 months.

Comment: Yes, @Ramhound I guess, today you - most presumably - opened this site for the first time. So your browser has fetched a fresh copy of the new certificate directly from the server. This 'effect' just seems to take place if you have visited the site before and an old copy of the cert. is already stored in your browser...
Thnx anyway!

Comment: Getting the old certificate is a client problem not a server problem

Answer (score 1):

The browser may obtain the page from the cache or from an existing open TLS session with the server, which means they'll never see the new certificate, which is only received in the TLS **handshake** stage. Close all browser windows to kill the existing sessions (and optionally restart your computer), then check if the problem persists.

**OLD ANSWER**

Chrome stores (caches) SSL certificates in the browser history. Instead of re-fetching them every time, Chrome reads them off the cache. In private mode the history is not used and nothing is saved to it, hence the new certificate is fetched

Source: [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/688828) on ServerFault.

This is the intended behavior (or a [bug in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=133351), depending who you ask) that was reported in 2012 (and closed as a duplicate of [this issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=496299)). Internet Explorer has [similar behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517272/why-does-internet-explorer-cache-expired-ssl-certificates-and-can-i-do-anything).

Comment: Hey @ikellenberger, I updated my answer to hopefully help regarding question A, but as to question B I'm clueless too :)

Comment: It does not make any sense. If it was a bug in 2012 its too long time. Is it real? I have the same problem right now. Exactly sometimes it load new certificate and sometimes old one with warning. What is that? I am sure certificates are renewed.